# Running consul in a container with UI

Tags: docker, consul

Following the [official documentation](https://hub.docker.com/_/consul/) I am running

```
docker run -d --name=dev-consul -e CONSUL_BIND_INTERFACE=eth0 consul -ui -p 8500:8500
```

I added -ui and -p 8500:8500 to enable consul UI.
But I cant really browse

```
http://localhost:8500/ui/
```

Or telnet 127.0.0.1 8500.

How can I browse consul UI when I am running it in docker?

Answer (score 5):

Try this command :

```
docker run --name consul -p 8500:8500 consul agent -dev -ui -client=0.0.0.0 -bind=0.0.0.0
```

Comment: According to current Consul docs, `-bind=0.0.0.0` is the default, and `-ui`  is on by default when running with `-dev`, so you can drop those two flags for simplicity - tested on Consul version 1.11.2

Answer (score 0):

You are binding to the eth0 so you need to use the ip address for eth0.

```
docker inspect dev-consul
```

Get the ip address and use the ip with the port like:

```
172.17.0.2:8500
```

Comment: I get "IPAddress": "" in the result